# Change CKeditor configuration dynamically based on dropdown

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

i have a language dropdown, i want my ck editor to open in selected dropdown language, but it is not happening. It works for first select but after that,but it stays there, does not change at all. i checked the dropdown values with alert and it is coming fine.

Here is my jquery code

```
    $(function() {
    $('.langdropdown').on('change', function() {
        $('#communication-message').val('');
        langval = $('.langdropdown').val();
        $('#communication-message').ckeditor({
            language: langval,
            uiColor: '#66FFCC'
        });
    });
 });
```

Comment: can you make jsfiddle of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#communication-message').ckeditor();
    $('.langdropdown').on("change", function () {
        var langCode = $(this).val();
        $($('#communication-message')).ckeditor(function () {
            this.destroy();
        }).ckeditor({
            language: langCode
        });
    });
});
```

A more comprehensive example to change language without changing the default CKEDitor settings.
JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/codeandcloud/u819q0og/

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript most of the time when an element has been initialized you have to 'destroy' then initialize the element again using the new values. I'd suggest you find a way of 'destroying' the current instance of ckeditor then creating a new one with the new params. Try the following. I have not tried but it should work.

```
   $(function() {
    $('.langdropdown').on('change', function() {
        var elem = $('#communication-message');
        var langval = $(this).val();
        elem.val('');
        elem.ckeditorGet().destroy();
        elem.ckeditor({
            language: langval,
            uiColor: '#66FFCC'
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you , but it also works for first change only.

Comment: I have changed the code a little bit. Try the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

So, one of the solution to my question is to create 2 divs outside the textbox and once the dropdown value changes, remove the internal div and append new textbox to outerdiv again.

```
$(function(){
$( '#communication-message' ).ckeditor({language:'en',uiColor:'#66FFCC'});
$('.langdropdown').on('change',function(){
$('.containerforck1').remove();
//alert('removed');
langval = $('.langdropdown').val();
$('.containerforck').append("<div class='containerforck1'><textarea id='communication-message'  name='message' rows='10' class='span6' required> </textarea></div>");
$( '#communication-message' ).ckeditor({language:langval,uiColor:'#66FFCC'});
});
});
```